# When i enter srtike "access granted" doesn't appear

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<string.h>

void main() {

    char a[20];

    cout<<"Please enter the required password"<<endl;

    cin>>a;

    if (a=="srtike"){

        cout<<"Access granted!"<<endl;

    }

    gets(a);

}
```

Comment: `if (a=="srtike"){` is unlikely to become true since you are comparing two pointers, not the characters. Use `strcmp()` in this case.

Comment: Why not print `a` first to see if you are comparing like with like? Also, you have marked this as C++, yet you are using C strings. You should use `std::string` instead of a character array

Comment: If you use **C strings in C++**: [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/), if you decide to fully **use C++**: [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/).

Comment: @RahulTripathi a char array doesn't have a `compare` method.

Comment: Dont use standard headers that end with `.h`.  the standard headers are `<iostream>` and `<string>`

Comment: @NathanOliver OP uses Turbo-C++ most likely..

Comment: the complier doesn't take headers without .h

Comment: please suggest me according to void main()

Comment: @ShikhharSiingh You should really think about updating your environment, if you're using Turbo C++ (which I think you do) then the C++ dialect used is from before C++ was standardized in 1998 (a *long* time ago). There are many free ("gratis") environments that comes with up-to-date compilers.

Comment: i'm a beginner ,please suggest me the simplest program for the same using "void main()"

Comment: then please suggest me a good platform/environment!

Comment: please suggest me somethin'!

Comment: LOL just two picks: Microsoft Visual C++ Express (if Windows)  or GCC (with IDE you prefer, if you want an IDE). But there are some more, take a tour.

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare arrays to string literals, what will happen is that the array decays to a pointer to the first character in the array, and you compare that pointer to the pointer for the string literal, which will always be false.

Instead, if you want to use C strings you should use [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp) to compare strings:

```
if (strcmp(a, "srtike") == 0)
{
    // the contents of a equals "srtike"
    ...
}
```

Otherwise I recommend you look into [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) which will allow comparisons like you have, because the `operator==` is overloaded.

Comment: can u please write me an alternative program for this cuz using i'm a beginner and I still haven't studied strcmp!

Comment: @ShikhharSiingh If you want to compare strings C-style, then there's no alternative, `strcmp` is the *only* function to use. And I have already shown you how to use it.